# Improper integral $\int_0^\infty \frac{e^{ix}}{x^{\alpha}} \, dx $ convergence(?) for $0< \alpha<1$.

Tags: convergence-divergence, improper-integrals

I came up with the following seemingly true statement:

> $$\int_0^\infty \frac{e^{ix}}{x^{\alpha}} \, dx $$
>
> for $\alpha \in (0,1)$ exists as an improper integral. Also, is it possible to compute the integral? For instance, the value of 
>   $$ \int_0^\infty \frac{e^{ix}}{ \sqrt{x}} \, dx = ? $$

My thoughts on convergence:

> The improper integral $\int_0^N \frac{e^{ix}}{x^{\alpha}} \, dx $ exists by DCT for all $N \in \mathbb{N}$. So it suffices to consider the cases, $$\int_N^\infty \frac{\cos x}{x^{\alpha}} \, dx , \int_N^\infty \frac{\sin x }{x^{\alpha} } \, dx .$$
>   Using integration by parts, we have 
>   $$ \int_N^M \frac{ \cos x }{x^{\alpha} } = \Big[ \frac{ \sin x }{x^{\alpha} } \Big]_N^M + \alpha \int_N^M \frac{ \sin x }{ x^{\alpha+1} } \, dx $$ 
>   which converges as $M \rightarrow \infty$. Since the latter is dominated by $\int_N^M \frac{1}{x^{\alpha+1}} \, dx $ of which converges. A similar argument holds for imaginary part.

Is this argument correct?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your argument is correct.

Furthermore, it is not too difficult to compute the value of your integral using some contour integration.

[Cauchy's Integral Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_theorem) supports the change of variables $x\mapsto ix$, which changes the path of integration from $[0,R]$ to $[0,-iR]$, followed by the change of path using the closed contour
$$
[0,R]\cup Re^{-i[0,\pi/2]}\cup[-iR,0]
$$
which contains no singularities of the integrand, giving
$$
\begin{align}
\int_0^\infty x^{-\alpha}e^{ix}\,\mathrm{d}x
&=e^{(1-\alpha)\pi i/2}\int_0^\infty x^{-\alpha}e^{-x}\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{e^{(1-\alpha)\pi i/2}\Gamma(1-\alpha)}
\end{align}
$$
Since $\Gamma\left(\frac12\right)=\sqrt\pi$, the value of the integral for $\alpha=\frac12$ is
$$
\int_0^\infty x^{-1/2}e^{ix}\,\mathrm{d}x=\sqrt{\frac\pi2}\,(1+i)
$$

Comment: shouldn't you deform your contour around zero?  $x=0$, which is a singularity of the integrated, is on your chosen contour, isn't it?

Comment: Since the integrals $\int_0^\infty x^{-\alpha}e^{ix}\,\mathrm{d}x$ and $\int_0^\infty x^{-\alpha}e^{-x}\,\mathrm{d}x$ converge near $0$, there will be no problem. If you are uncomfortable with that, you can stop those integrals at a distance $\epsilon\gt0$ from $0$ and splice in a quarter circle of radius $\epsilon$. The length of the quarter circle will be $\frac\pi2\epsilon$ and the absolute value of the integrand will be $\le\epsilon^{-\alpha}$; thus, the absolute value of the integral along that quarter circle will be $\le\frac\pi2\epsilon^{1-\alpha}\to0$ as $\epsilon\to0$.

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
\left.\int_{0}^{\infty}{\expo{\ic x} \over x^{\alpha}}\,\dd x
\,\right\vert_{\ \alpha\ \in\ \pars{0,1}} & =
\int_{0}^{\infty}\expo{\ic x}\
\overbrace{{1 \over \Gamma\pars{\alpha}}
\int_{0}^{\infty}t^{\alpha - 1}\expo{-xt}\,\dd t}
^{\ds{1 \over x^{\alpha}}}\ \,\dd x
\\[5mm] & =
{1 \over \Gamma\pars{\alpha}}
\int_{0}^{\infty}t^{\alpha - 1}\int_{0}^{\infty}\expo{-\pars{t - \ic}x}
\,\dd x\,\dd t
\\[5mm] & =
{1 \over \Gamma\pars{\alpha}}
\int_{0}^{\infty}{t^{\alpha - 1} \over t - \ic}\,\dd t =
{1 \over \Gamma\pars{\alpha}}\bracks{%
\int_{0}^{\infty}{t^{\alpha} \over t^{2} + 1}\,\dd t +
\ic\int_{0}^{\infty}{t^{\alpha - 1} \over t^{2} + 1}\,\dd t}
\\[5mm] & =
{1 \over \Gamma\pars{\alpha}}\bracks{%
{1 \over 2}\int_{0}^{\infty}{t^{\alpha/2 - 1/2} \over t + 1}\,\dd t +
{1 \over 2}\,\ic\int_{0}^{\infty}{t^{\alpha/2 - 1} \over t + 1}\,\dd t}
\\[5mm] & =
{1 \over 2\,\Gamma\pars{\alpha}}\bracks{%
\mrm{B}\pars{{\alpha + 1 \over 2},{1 - \alpha \over 2}} +
\ic\,\mrm{B}\pars{{\alpha \over 2},1 - {\alpha \over 2}}}
\end{align}

> The [last integrals involve identities](http://dlmf.nist.gov/5.12.E3) which are expressed in terms of the *Beta Function* $\ds{\mrm{B}}$.

Note that, with *Euler Reflection Formula*, 
$\ds{\mrm{B}\pars{a,1 - a} = {\pi \over \sin\pars{\pi a}}}$ such that
\begin{align}
\left.\int_{0}^{\infty}{\expo{\ic x} \over x^{\alpha}}\,\dd x
\,\right\vert_{\ \alpha\ \in\ \pars{0,1}} & =
{1 \over 2\,\Gamma\pars{\alpha}}\bracks{{\pi \over \cos\pars{\pi\alpha/2}} +
\ic\,{\pi \over \sin\pars{\pi\alpha/2}}}
\\[5mm] & =
{\pi \over \Gamma\pars{\alpha}\sin\pars{\pi\alpha}}\,
\bracks{\sin\pars{\pi\alpha \over 2} + \ic\cos\pars{\pi\alpha \over 2}} =
\bbx{\Gamma\pars{1 - \alpha}\ic\expo{-\ic\pi\alpha/2}}
\end{align}

> Note that, with *Euler Reflection Formula*,
>   $\ds{{\pi \over \Gamma\pars{\alpha}\sin\pars{\pi\alpha}} =
> \Gamma\pars{1 - \alpha}}$.

Comment: Would you please explain the step? \begin{align}\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-(t - i)x}dx={1 \over t - i}\end{align}

Comment: @MathArt Set first $\displaystyle z = \left(t - \mathrm{i}\right)x$.

Comment: Cool. That will be self-explaining.

Answer (score 0):

Can be another way of substituting $x=\xi^2$ in
$\int_0^\infty\frac{e^{ix}}{\sqrt{x}}\, dx=2\int_0^\infty e^{i\xi^2}d\xi$

Then refer to:
[Is it a coincidence that the $x^2$, and $x^3$ of $\cos$ and sinusoidal integrals relate to Gamma functions?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3798700/is-it-a-coincidence-that-the-x2-and-x3-of-cos-and-sinusoidal-integrals/3798724#3798724)