# How to calculate this integral with complex number

Tags: integration

I am new to SE.
I want to calculate this definite integral, but it contains complex numbers. How can I solve it?

$$\int\limits_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \frac{e^{\mathrm i x}}{x} \mathrm dx$$

Comment: Do you know complex analysis?

Comment: I'm a new mathematician. I've only heard about complex analysis, but I haven't started to learn yet.

Comment: See [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2372115/improper-integral-int-0-infty-fraceixx-alpha-dx-convergence).

Comment: That integral diverges.  So you need to say more about how you want it interpreted.

Comment: Do you know that $e^{i x} = \cos x + i \sin x$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does converge if we take the Cauchy Principle value of the integral. 
We can rewrite our integral as the following:
$$\lim_{s \to \infty}\int_{-s}^{s}{\frac{e^{ix}}{x}}dx=\lim_{s \to \infty}\int_{-s}^{s}{\frac{cos(x)+isin(x)}{x}}dx=\lim_{s \to \infty}\int_{-s}^{s}{\frac{cos(x)}{x}}+\lim_{s\to \infty} i\int_{-s}^{s}\frac{sin(x)}{x}dx$$
The integral containing $\frac{cos(x)}{x}$ has an integrand which is odd. If you remember, the integral of an odd function over symmetric bounds is just $0$. This should make sense because the area of $\frac{cos(x)}{x}$ is symmetric over the x-axis which means the area from $x=0$ to $x=\infty$ cancels out with the area from $x=-\infty$ to $x=0$ Therefore:
$$\lim_{s \to \infty}\int_{-s}^{s}{\frac{cos(x)}{x}}=0$$
Which means:
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{\frac{e^{ix}}{x}}dx=i\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{\frac{sin(x)}{x}}dx$$
$\frac{sin(x)}{x}$ is an even function which means we can rewrite the integral as:
$$2i\int_{0}^{\infty}{\frac{sin(x)}{x}}dx=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{\frac{e^{ix}}{x}}dx$$
We are now going to parameterize our integral containing $\frac{sin(x)}{x}$
$$f(t)=2i\int_{0}^{\infty}{\frac{sin(x)}{x}e^{-tx}}dx$$
Notice that $f(0)$ will give us the integral we wanted to evaluate.
$$Leibniz$$ $$Rule:$$
$$\frac{d}{dt}\int_{a}^{b}{f(x,t)}dx=\int_{a}^{b}{\frac{\partial}{\partial t}f(x,t)}dx$$
We will now use Leibniz Rule to differentiate $f(t)$
$$f'(t)=\frac{d}{dt}2i\int_{0}^{\infty}{\frac{sin(x)}{x}e^{-tx}}dx=2i\int_{0}^{\infty}{\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\frac{sin(x)}{x}e^{-tx}}dx=2i\int_{0}^{\infty}{-sin(x)e^{-tx}}dx$$ 
Our new integral is easy to evaluate. Just use integration by parts and plug in the bounds. The final result of our integral is:
$$f'(t)=-2i\frac{1}{t^2+1}$$
We have found $f'(t)$, but want to find f(t). So all we have to do is integrate $f'(t)$ to recover f(t)
$$f(t)=\int{-2i\frac{1}{t^2+1}}=-2iarctan(t)+c=2i\int_{0}^{\infty}{\frac{sin(x)}{x}e^{-tx}}dx$$ 
notice that our integral goes to $0$ if t goes to $\infty$ which means $f(\infty)=0$
$$f(\infty)=-2iarctan(\infty)+c=-2i\frac{\pi}{2}+c=-\pi i+c=0$$
$$c=i\pi$$
$$f(t)=-2iarctan(t)+i\pi=2i\int_{0}^{\infty}{\frac{sin(x)}{x}e^{-tx}}dx$$
remember that f(0) gives us the answer to your integral. Therefore:
$$f(0)=-2iarctan(0)+i\pi=i\pi=2i\int_{0}^{\infty}{\frac{sin(x)}{x}}dx=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{\frac{e^{ix}}{x}}dx$$
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{\frac{e^{ix}}{x}}dx=i\pi$$
Hopefully this helps. This can also be solved using residue theorem and complex contour integration, but this is a more understood method.

Answer (score 5):

If the question is only to avoid complex numbers, compute
$$
\int \frac{\cos x}{x}\;dx\quad\text{and}\quad \int\frac{\sin x}{x}\;dx
$$
The first diverges (pole at $x=0$), the second converges (as an improper integral).

This is because of the useful property (or even definition) $e^{ix} = \cos x +i \sin x$.