# Is it a coincidence that the $x^2$, and $x^3$ of $\cos$ and sinusoidal integrals relate to Gamma functions?

Tags: real-analysis, gamma-function

Is there any generalization of
$$
\int_0^\infty\cos(\xi^k)d\xi=\frac{\Gamma\left(\frac 1 k\right)}{2\sqrt k}\quad?
$$
It is surprisingly valid for $k=2,3$ and $\sin$ as well, but not for other $k$.

Comment: It would seem $$ \int_0^\infty\cos(x^k)dx=\cos(\frac{\pi}{2k})\frac{\Gamma(1/k)}{k}. $$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using a change of contour for the last integral you have something like:
$$ \int_0^\infty e^{i \xi^k} d\xi =  \frac1k \int_0^\infty e^{it} t^{1/k-1} dt =\frac1k  i^{1/k} \int_0^\infty e^{-u} u^{1/k-1} du =\frac1k i^{1/k} \Gamma(1/k). $$

Comment: Lost the $1/k $

Comment: @runway44 Thanks for the reminder!

Comment: Super! Would it be direct to show that $\frac1k \int_0^\infty e^{it} t^{1/k-1} dt =\frac1k  i^{1/k} \int_0^\infty e^{-u} u^{1/k-1} du$? Implying $\int_0^\infty f(x) d x= \int_0^{i\infty} f(x) d x$

Comment: @MathArt It is fairly easy with complex analysis if you are familiar with that. You define the holomorphic function $f(z)=e^{iz} z^{1/k-1}$ with a cut e.g. along ${\Bbb R}_-$. The integral along the boundary of $r<|z|<1/r$,  $0<{\rm Arg}z <\pi/2$ then vanishes. Letting $r$ go to zero you get the result.

Answer (score 3):

Broadly speaking (ignoring branches), let $x= \xi^k$, $x^{1/k} = \xi$, $\frac{d\xi}{dx} = \frac{1}{k}x^{\frac{1}{k}-1}$
$$
I = \int_0^\infty  \frac{1}{k}x^{\frac{1}{k}-1} \cos(x) \; dx
$$
compare this to a [Mellin transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mellin_transform). Because $\cos$ and $\sin$ are made out of exponential functions, also consider that
$$
\Gamma(s) = \int_0^\infty x^{s-1}e^{-x} \; dx
$$
so we can see the origin of $\Gamma(1/k)$, in fact, many functions are related to gamma functions through their Mellin transforms.

For Mellin transforms in general we have
$$
\mathcal{M}[f(x^k)](s) = \frac{1}{k}\mathcal{M}[f(x)](\frac{s}{k})
$$
we have the Mellin transform of $\cos(x)$
$$
\mathcal{M}[\cos(x)](s) = \int_0^\infty x^{s-1} \cos(x) \; dx = \cos \left(\frac{\pi  s}{2}\right) \Gamma (s)
$$
$$
\mathcal{M}[\cos(x^k)](s) = \int_0^\infty x^{s-1} \cos(x^k) \; dx = \frac{1}{k}\cos \left(\frac{\pi  s}{2k}\right) \Gamma \left(\frac{s}{k}\right)
$$
your integral is for $s=1$
$$
\int_0^\infty\cos(x^k) \; dx = \frac{1}{k}\cos \left(\frac{\pi }{2k}\right) \Gamma (\frac{1}{k})
$$
your example works because $\frac{1}{3}\cos(\frac{\pi}{2\cdot 3})=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2 \cdot 3} = \frac{1}{2 \sqrt{3}}$.

**In terms of a generalisation** for any random function one chooses, consider a very general series, e.g. a hypergeometric function. which has Mellin transform
$$
\mathcal{M}[_2F_1(a,b,c,-d x)](s) =  \frac{\Gamma (c) d^{-s} \Gamma (s) \Gamma (a-s) \Gamma (b-s)}{\Gamma (a) \Gamma (b) \Gamma (c-s)}
$$
we have
$$
\mathcal{M}[_2F_1(a,b,c,-d x^k)](s) =  \frac{\Gamma (c) d^{-\frac{s}{k}} \Gamma (\frac{s}{k}) \Gamma (a-\frac{s}{k}) \Gamma (b-\frac{s}{k})}{k\Gamma (a) \Gamma (b) \Gamma (c-\frac{s}{k})}
$$
so for example, in principle using $\;_2F_1(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2};1;x) = \frac{2}{\pi} K(x)$, with elliptic $K$ function, we have in analogy
$$
\frac{2}{\pi}\int_0^\infty x^{s-1} K(-\eta x^k) \; dx = \frac{\Gamma (1) \eta^{-\frac{s}{k}} \Gamma (\frac{s}{k}) \Gamma (\frac{1}{2}-\frac{s}{k}) \Gamma (\frac{1}{2}-\frac{s}{k})}{k\Gamma (\frac{1}{2}) \Gamma (\frac{1}{2}) \Gamma (1-\frac{s}{k})}
$$
**whether this converges or not** will depend on various technical details. This last example is just to show that the gamma functions do not relate in particular to sinusoidal functions, but most analytic functions, which are definable using a generalized contour integral, along with the integration region $[0,\infty)$. In general, wherever gamma functions are found, some kind of relationship to a Mellin transform is not far away.

Comment: "Mellin transform" had been for a long time challenge for me. But the founding of a fantastic formula is the least for me to enjoy: $\int_0^\infty\cos(x^k) \; dx = \frac{1}{k}\cos \left(\frac{\pi }{2k}\right) \Gamma (\frac{1}{k})$.